# Trying to follow the tutorial on PyMC3, it comes to: "'Model' object has no attribute TransformedVar"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pymc3

I have been trying to follow the tutorial on PYMC3 https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/getting_started/, but when I get to the following section of code, I run into errors...

```
from pymc3 import Exponential, T, logtransform, exp, Deterministic
from pymc3.distributions.timeseries import GaussianRandomWalk


with Model() as sp500_model:

    nu = Exponential('nu', 1./10, testval=.1)

    sigma, log_sigma = sp500_model.TransformedVar('sigma', Exponential.dist(1./.02, testval=.1),
                                        logtransform)

    s = GaussianRandomWalk('s', sigma**-2, shape=n)

    volatility_process = Deterministic('volatility_process', exp(-2*s))

    r = T('r', nu, lam=volatility_process, observed=returns)
```

The first error is "cannot import name `logtransform`".
The second error (if I do not try to load `logtransform`) is "'Model' object has no attribute `TransformedVar`".

I am running this in IPython Notebook on Windows 7, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling PyMC3 to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current version of pymc3 is out of sync with [the tutorial](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/getting_started/).

[`TransformedVar` was removed](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/commit/7eb81116e5893098d316a9911e788d2bb57eba25#diff-1f25198dab6a35cd27fffe043b7e1b9dL151) on 2015-06-03.

[`pymc3.logtransform` was removed](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/commit/f159733c56e0363cddb250e1bfe0b347506c69fb) on 2015-06-15.

The new way of doing it [no longer requires TransformedVar](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/commit/4bb9d47819103b7df699b87e1f35509e89eae25e#diff-82a735e366da24e62b2e1d9ece8c1c7eL56):

```
 sigma, log_sigma = model.TransformedVar(
     'sigma', Exponential.dist(1. / .02, testval=.1),
     logtransform)
```

is replaced by

```
 sigma = Exponential('sigma', 1. / .02, testval=.1)
```

Your installation of pymc3 should contain `pymc3/examples/stochastic_volatility.py`.
Unlike the online tutorial, this code should be consistent with your version of pymc3.

The reason why the code can be simplified this way is because `Exponential` was made a subclass of `PositiveContinuous`, and this class [uses the logtransform by default](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/commit/c3120bce05bf8f1389272e1c38ddf83cb46c8d84#diff-1837763aea633f0d6324583c00051d83R21).

---

For the record, here is the current version of stochastic_volatility.py ([as of 2015-06-04](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/4bb9d47819103b7df699b87e1f35509e89eae25e/pymc3/examples/stochastic_volatility.py#L54)):

```
from matplotlib.pylab import *
import numpy as np
from pymc3 import *
from pymc3.distributions.timeseries import *

from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
from scipy import optimize

n = 400

returns = np.genfromtxt(get_data_file('pymc3.examples', "data/SP500.csv"))[-n:]
returns[:5]

model = Model()
with model:
    sigma= Exponential('sigma', 1. / .02, testval=.1)

    nu = Exponential('nu', 1. / 10)

    s = GaussianRandomWalk('s', sigma ** -2, shape=n)

    r = T('r', nu, lam=exp(-2 * s), observed=returns)


def run(n=2000):
    if n == "short":
        n = 50
    with model:
        start = find_MAP(vars=[s], fmin=optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b)
        step = NUTS(model.vars, scaling=start, gamma=.25)
        trace = sample(5, step, start)

        # Start next run at the last sampled position.
        start2 = trace.point(-1)
        step2 = NUTS(model.vars, scaling=start2, gamma=.25)
        trace = sample(n, step2, trace=trace)

    # <codecell>

    # figsize(12,6)
    title(str(s))
    plot(trace[s][::10].T, 'b', alpha=.03)
    xlabel('time')
    ylabel('log volatility')

    # figsize(12,6)
    traceplot(trace, model.vars[:-1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

---

I found this by cloning pymc3 from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3
```

and then looking through the commits that affected transforms.py:

```
gitk pymc3/distributions/transforms.py 
gitk pymc3/distributions/continuous.py
gitk pymc3/examples/stochastic_volatility.py
```

Once the commit hash has been found (e.g. c3120bce05bf8f1389272e1c38ddf83cb46c8d84), the 
corresponding commit on github can be located at:

```
https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/commit/c3120bce05bf8f1389272e1c38ddf83cb46c8d84
```

I wasn't able to find [a github issue](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen) during the relevant time period (2015-06-xx) which discussed/explained this change.